# Find the value, given the error formula for trapezoid rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The global error of $\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x$, between two
$x$-values by the trapezoidal rule is
$-(1/12)h^3f''(ξ)$

a) $f(x) = x^3, x := [0.2,0.5]$

Find the value for $ξ$. Not really sure where to start with this problem. We never did any examples in class.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis

Comment: Linking a wikipedia article doesn't help me figure out how to go through the process. I can look things up on wikipedia. I just don't know how to find what the problem is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

you have $$\frac14\left(0.5^4 - 0.2^4\right)=\int_{0.2}^{0.5}x^3 \,dx = 0.3\left(\frac12 0.2^2 + \frac120.3^2\right) -\frac1{12}(0.3^3) 6\xi \tag 1 $$

equation $(1)$ determines what $\xi$ is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

Find the actual value of the integral.

Find the trapezoidal rule estimate.

Get the difference between the two.
That is the error.

Since the error is of the form
$-(1/12)h^3f''(ξ)$,
and you know $h$ and $f$
(and therefore $f''$),
find $ξ$
from the error,
$h$,
and $f''$.